# How can use <s:if> tag in Struts 2?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, displaytag, ognl

I have the below Struts 2 tag, I need to check if property `value="#attr.row.Commentaire` is not empty and if it's not, display a small icon where the user can click it and consult the contents of the property `value="#attr.row.Commentaire`.

How can I use the `<s:if>` tag of Struts 2 efficiently to do that?

```jsp
<display:column title="Commentaire" sortable="true" sortProperty="Commentaire"
    class="alerte_td_commentaire">              
<s:property value="#attr.row.Commentaire"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code

```
<s:if test="#attr.row.Commentaire != null && #attr.row.Commentaire != ''">
```

The [`if` tag](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/if-tag.html) uses the `test` attribute to evaluate [OGNL](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/ognl.html) expression to a boolean value.

You may also want to use an [`a` tag](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/a-tag.html) which renders a HTML anchor tag that could be used combined with the `if` tag to

> consult the contents of the property

There's also a `debug` tag that could be used to wrap other tags to show you a link that will render a debug data.

```
<s:debug>  
 <s:property value="%{#attr.row.Commentaire}"/>
</s:debug>
```

Comment: after my if clause I added <img id="hello" title="Modifier et commenter la donnée" src="/img/icons/ico_comment.png" "=""> which worked fine and displayed an icon, what I am woundering if its possible to add javascript that activates when onclick on the icon to display the value of   value="%{#attr.row.Commentaire}" ??

Comment: @john You should write the `onclick` handler and use `alert('<s:property value="%{#attr.row.Commentaire}"/>');` or make use of javascript framework to apply UI widgets to the handler. Anyway mixing such java and javascript works if you want to pass a value from the server to the client.